# How to apply the localstorage to List Itemtpl dynamically in Sencha

Tags: extjs

How to apply the **localstorage** to List **Itemtpl** dynamically in Sencha

Comment: Your question is far too vague. Localstorage is just a type of proxy tied to a datastore. A list works off the datastore, using templates. Are you having trouble getting templates to work with datastore, or datastore to work with proxy?

Comment: Actually i am having json data in local storage i want to bind the localstorage data(json data) to the list item tpl.

Comment: Is your localstorage proxy attached to an actual datastore? You need to do that and set the store on the list.

Comment: yes i got that solution,can u please say me how to change the UI theme according to the device(windows, iphone, android, etc).